# Retrieving images in Laravel response 404

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems

in my web application i save users avatar with this method:

```
$avatarPath = request()->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
```

then i store $avatarPath in the database. to display the avatar on page i use:

```
<img class="doc-avatar"  src="{{ Storage::disk('local')->url($doctor->image) }}" />
```

but as you guess there wont be any image and i don`t know why.

i created a symbolic link with:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

also checked the avatars folder in storage/app/public/avatars and my images are in there.

i can get all meta data about image with

```
Storage::url($doctor->image);
```

or

```
Storage::size($doctor->image);
```

but if i copy the returned URL in the browser there would be 404 error.

http://localhost:8080/storage/avatars/04it83vKYnobT7l8dNXwt1pE0VxiT9L5lQPQ6A1Z.jpeg

http://localhost/storage/avatars/04it83vKYnobT7l8dNXwt1pE0VxiT9L5lQPQ6A1Z.jpeg

both return 404.

and here is my config/filesystem.php

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public'),

'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
  ],
```

Comment: are you uploading them to public folder ?

Comment: not in the public/storage/avatars... all of the are uploading in the storage/app/public/avatars

Comment: Try `<img class="doc-avatar"  src="{{ asset(Storage::get($doctor->image)) }}" />`

Comment: HTTP request has permission to read files inside public folder,  You need to give permission to read from other folder

Comment: @MahdiYounesi yeah. thats why i created a symbolic link between public folder and storage folder. i guess? i dont think changing permission of my storage folder is a right move.

Comment: @JeuneGuerrier <img src(unknown) class="doc-avatar"> this is what your code print in the html template.
and my problem is that even if i hard code the url of image nothing would return. all i get is a 404 error.

Comment: Try this `<img class="doc-avatar" src="{{ asset('avatar/'.$doctor->image) }}" />`

Answer (score 0):

the upload will add the images to `storage/app/public/avatars`, also double check if the files are synced to `public/avatars`. files under public folder are the only ones accessible not the ones under `storage/app/public/avatars`.